# Adding markers to Leaflet MiniMap?

Tags: leaflet, markers

I am using Leaflet with the MiniMap plugin:
https://github.com/Norkart/Leaflet-MiniMap

Often, the zoom level difference between main map and mini map is so big that the bounding box shown in the minimap cannot be seen.

Can I set a marker on the minimap in this case? Or are there other solutions e.g. a minimum size for the bounding box on the mini map?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about "often zoom level difference is so big"? What are the settings of map and plugin when this happens? How does it look like (picture)?